# How to convert AM and to PM?

Tags: python

I want to get time write a program that asks the user for

1. an hour between 1 and 12
2. am or pm
3. how many hours into the future they want to go

and print out the hour they should be leaving

Is the below program correct?

Ex
Input : 11:05 am   ;2 hr
Output : 1:05 pm

```
user = eval(input('enter hour :'))
    day = input('enter am (1) or pm (2) :')
    hour = eval(input('How many hours ahead ?:'))
    hour += user
    if hour > 24:
        print('cant convert that time.')
    elif hour >= 1 and hour <= 12 and day == '1':
        print(f'New hour : {hour}', end='am')
        print()
    elif hour > 12 and hour <= 24 and day == '1':
        hour = hour - 12
        print(f'New hour : {hour}', end='pm')
        print()
    elif hour >= 12 and hour <= 24 and day == '2':
        hour = hour - 12
        print(f'New hour : {hour}', end='pm')
        print()
```

Write a program that asks the user for an hour between 1 and 12, asks them to enter am or pm,
and asks them how many hours into the future they want to go. Print out what the hour will
be that many hours into the future, printing am or pm as appropriate. An example is shown
below

Comment: I do not believe this is correct, consider the case where `user = 12`, `day = 'am'` and `hour = 13`. You're result of the addition will be `hour = 25` which will print that it can not convert that time, when in reality it is not unrealistic to want to travel 13 hours into the future. The expected result would be 1 PM but you would print can't convert. [Timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) will definitely be your friend

Comment: This is likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

```
user = eval(input('enter hour :'))
day = input('enter am (1) or pm (2) :')
hour = eval(input('How many hours ahead ?:'))


if day == 'pm' and user != 12:
    user += 12;
elif day == 'am' and user == 12:
    user = 0;

new_hour = user + hour;
new_hour = new_hour % 24;

    
if new_hour >= 0 and new_hour < 12:
    new_hour = new_hour % 12 ;
    if new_hour == 0:
        new_hour = 12;
    print(f'New hour : {new_hour}', end='am')
    print()
else:
    new_hour = new_hour % 12;
    if new_hour == 0:
        new_hour = 12 ;
    print(f'New hour : {new_hour}', end='pm')
    print()
```

> a % b = remainder of a divided by b

Code explanation:

1- Take the user's input which is in hour and date in am pm format.

```
user = eval(input('enter hour :'))
day = input('enter am (1) or pm (2) :')
hour = eval(input('How many hours ahead ?:'))
```

2- Transform it to 24 format. Ex: 1pm becomes 13, 12 am becomes 0, etc.

```
if day == 'pm' and user != 12:
    user += 12;
elif day == 'am' and user == 12:
    user = 0;
```

3- add the transformed date (in 24 format) to the number of hours the user wants and store that value in `new_hour`

```
new_hour = user + hour;
```

4- Now `new_hour` holds the result in 24 format. We need to transform back to am pm format.
So Divide `new_hour` by 24 and take the reminder.
Ex: if `new_hour = 27` --> `new_hour % 24 = 3`

```
new_hour = new_hour % 24;
```

5-
Remember that `new_hour` is still in 24 hour format.
So:
If :  0 <= `new_hour` < 12 --> the new date to print is AM

Else --> the new date to print is PM

```
if new_hour >= 0 and new_hour < 12:
        new_hour = new_hour % 12 ;
        if new_hour == 0:
            new_hour = 12;
        print(f'New hour : {new_hour}', end='am')
        print()
else:
    new_hour = new_hour % 12;
    if new_hour == 0:
        new_hour = 12 ;
    print(f'New hour : {new_hour}', end='pm')
    print()
```

Comment: This code workds. Ask if there is something not clear.

Comment: Note that I updated the answer. There was a bug before the update but it is fixed now

Comment: This code does not work. Consider the case where `user = 12`, `day = am`, and `hour=12`. Your code will set `hour=24` then when doing `hour = hour%24` you set `hour=0`. You're result will print `New hour : 0 am` when expected result is 12 PM

Comment: please @ EEAH explain why use reminder operator can someone tell me is the a math issue or programming knowledge issue  because am thinking am a bad programmer as a new person

Comment: @ganiyu I updated the answer and wrote a new code because the old one had a bug mentioned in the comment by plum 0. I also explained the entire code.

Comment: @EEAH It's getting closer but still not entirely there when traveling for > 24 hours. Consider the inputs `user = 12 day =  'pm'  hour='25'` The expected result would be 1 pm. The actual result would be as follows: `new_hour = 37 new_hour = 13` which would then print "New hour: 0 pm". I believe the print statements should still be %12 with an if check to determine if the mod results in 0.

I've been running into this issue with my own unposted solution. +1 for the fixes and explanation tho

Comment: @plum0 Yes. I updated the answer and fixed the code. There should not be more unhandled cases.

Comment: @ganiyu The code has been updated again. Don't forget to check the new code and not the old one

Comment: @EEAH I believe you are correct, from what I can tell it appears to handle all edge cases. A few things I would do differently that is purely a stylistic thing: create a `result_hour = new_hour % 12 if new_hour % 12 != 0 else 12` prior to checking if it is am or pm and print the new variable (removes redundant code from your am/pm if statements). I would also add the newline character `'\n'` to the end parameter of the print() statements rather than calling print again. `print(f'New Hour: {result_hour}', end='am\n')`

Comment: @plum 0  Yes. As for styling a lot can be done. Ex writing functions for "general" use like one that transforms a 24 hour format to am pm and vive versa, and more. But I tried providing the solution with minimal changes to the original question's variables and style, just to try and keep it simple and easier for the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use datetime/ timedelta objects here is a solution for that. Using a time delta and datetime results in not needing to handle the edge case where the `new_time` is > 24 hours, as it is already handled with the python built-in. This is perhaps overkill for this solution.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Get User Input
user = eval(input('enter hour :'))
day = input('enter am (1) or pm (2) :')
hour = eval(input('How many hours ahead ?:'))

# Convert time to 24 hour format suitable for datetime object (12 AM = 0, 12 PM = 12)
if day == 'pm' and user != 12:
    user +=12
elif day == 'am' and user == 12:
    user = 0

# Create a datetime object since time objects cant have hours > 24
curr_time = datetime(year=1,month=1,day=1, hour=user)
time_delta = timedelta(hours=hour)
new_time = curr_time + time_delta

# Pull out just the hour from our datetime object
new_hour = new_time.time().hour

# convert the result hour back to 12 hour format and print it.
result_hour = new_hour % 12 if new_hour%12 != 0 else 12
if new_hour >= 0 and new_hour < 12:
    print(f"New Hour: {result_hour} am")
else:
    print(f"New Hour: {result_hour} pm")
```

Comment: and CobyC thank you for the answer solving, can i ask how long did it take to work that work am a bit curious  as a new programmer and can you tell me if this is a more math and logical thinking or just one has to be good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

When working with time and date it's best to use datetime or timedelta.

```
from datetime import timedelta
   
user = eval(input('enter start hour :'))
user_start_time = timedelta(hours=user)
    
day = eval(input('enter am (1) or pm (2) :'))
    
default_start_time = timedelta(hours=0)  # am
if day == 2:
    default_start_time = timedelta(hours=12)  # pm
    
actual_start = default_start_time + user_start_time
    
hour = eval(input('How many hours ahead ?:'))
time_to_add = timedelta(hours=hour)
    
future_time = default_start_time + user_start_time + time_to_add
    
print(future_time)
    
if future_time > timedelta(hours=12):
    print("PM")
else:
    print("AM")
```

Comment: @ganiyu to be honest, sometimes it just comes with experience, or a lot of googling :-)